# SQL SP_WHO insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to add a where clause into the below statement but cant figure our the syntax

```
INSERT INTO #tmpUsers EXEC SP_WHO
```

I want to add `WHERE loginame = 'myname'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sql 2008 you can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @tmpUsers table ( spid INT, ecid INT, STATUS VARCHAR(MAX), loginame VARCHAR(50), hostname VARCHAR(50), blk BIT, 
dbname VARCHAR(MAX), cmd VARCHAR(MAX), request_id INT ) 

INSERT INTO @tmpUsers
EXEC sp_who @loginame  = 'sa'

SELECT * FROM @tmpUsers
```

You can see the reference on the parameters here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx

Comment: +1, and don't forget you can view the original source code for sp_who using SSMS.  From there you can create your own version (preferably with a different name) where you can pass in more/different parameters or make any changes necessary.

Comment: You can see the definition with `EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_who'` though that stored procedure is quite long in the tooth now.  [Who is Active](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx) is well worth a look.

Comment: Or just open the Master database and look under System Stored Procedures